# Node.js retaining POST data after rendering page even on multiple devices?

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, express

So I'm learning Express.js and Node.js and I've got a simple site that on POST request on a page, it uses an API to gather images, then displays them on the page.

I basically have a middleware function that gathers the image links from the post parameter and puts them into a global array, then the post routing function renders the page with the links.

It does this successfully but if I go back and then try with a different image set it'll just instantly dump out the previous results as if nothings changed - if I then hit refresh it gives me the correct images.

I don't understand what's happening.. I also tried clearly the global array after rendering the page but no improvements.

I've done it on multiple devices. E.g. Use laptop to load up image set 1, it'll display image set one, then use mobile to load up image set 2, and it'll display image set 1, if I then refresh on mobile I'll get image set 2.

Ideas?

Comment: Could you provide your code?

Comment: @JohannesReuter I answered it, I found the issue myself, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.

I was calling the next() method outside of the call carrying out the link gathering, moving it to the final call of it fixed it.